# Java create native keyPress

Tags: java, windows, swing, awt

Is it possible to publish `KeyEvent` with custom parameters like:

```
new KeyEvent(w, KeyEvent.KEY_TYPED, System.currentTimeMillis(), 0, KeyEvent.VK_UNDEFINED, 'Z', KEY_LOCATION_UNKNOWN);
```

Because

```
java.awt.Robot.keyPress(int keycode);
```

doesn't allow to pass any parameters except keycode.

Is it possible to publish KeyEvent on OS level like it done by Robot?

Thanks

Comment: Did you take a look at `dispatchEvent()` method? See Javadoc of [Component](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#dispatchEvent(java.awt.AWTEvent))

Comment: `dispatchEvent()` creates event inside AWT Application. And such event will not be published on OS level.

Comment: *And such event will not be published on OS level.* - you would probably need to use JNI or JNA if you want to use OS level events. I have no idea how to do it. What is your issue you are trying to solve? Why do you think you need to customize the parameters?

Comment: Our application listens global events using `jnativehook` but sometimes we need to generate some keyTyped events. And such events should be handled by OS, but on application side (On NativeKeyListener) we need to check is our event or not.